# Why are some legs of a SID considered transitions, even when there's only one?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts, departure-sid

For example, consider the BAYPO8 departure from Tampa (KTPA). The CAMJO waypoint is the final waypoint on a rather linear route that does not contain other final waypoints. The second page of the FAA plate says that CAMJO is a transition.

[image]

[image]

But if you look at the ENDED8 departure (also from Tampa), there is no such designation on the LACEN waypoint. Although, coincidentally, *it was considered a transition in previous AIRAC cycles*.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After some digging and exploratory route planning in ForeFlight, it seems I've arrived at an answer that satisfies me: **the last waypoint is listed as a transition only if the departure officially ends prior to it, and flying to the transition is optional.** If there are other (more correct or plausible) answers, I'd still love to hear them.

The text description of each plate describes where the SID ends. In the case of BAYPO8, the last instruction is *on-track to BAYPO*. In the case of ENDED8, the text describes *on-track to LACEN*. So, it would seem that flying to LACEN is required when assigned the ENDED8 departure, however flying to CAMJO is optional for the BAYPO8, because you can drop off the procedure after BAYPO.

This is supported by the route planning features of ForeFlight. When I selected BAYPO8, and then "No Transition," my route of flight for the departure ended at BAYPO. I also had the option to choose the CAMJO transition. This is also supported by analysis of other similar departures that include only one final waypoint option.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the CAMJO designation as a transition on the BAYPO Eight DP is that there are two possible transitions for the BAYPO DP. A similar comment on the ENDED EIGHT DP isn't needed as there is only one transition fix.

Look at the title of the BAYPO Eight DP.  It is (BAYPO8.BAYPO) which indicates that BAYPO is the transition fix. The CAMJO TRANSITION (BAYPO8.CAMJO) statement on the back indicates that CAMJO is also available as a transition fix. You'll note that BAYPO transition is not listed on the back.

The ENDED EIGHT DP is titled (ENDED8.LACEN). As LACEN is the only transition fix, there is no reason to list it again so it doesn't appear on the back.

Some DPs have several transitions. Typically, the first one is listed in the title with the alternate transitions listed on the back.

If you are loading the departure into an FMS, it loaded sequentially. Select a departure runway and then you can select a DP that works with that runway. Once you select the DP, you can select a transition from the list of transitions for that DP.